# extracting columns with a certain name. dataframe python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with many columns but among them there are six columns named: people_emotions_anger, people_emotions_joy, people_emotions_surprise end so on.

Is there any clever way to extract only those columns which have prefix "people_emotions"?

I know i can extract every single column and then merge them into new dataframe but maybe there is more efficient way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source DF:

```
In [28]: df
Out[28]:
   aaa_1  aaa_2 bbb_1 bbb_2  aaa_3
0      1      2   aaa   xxx     10
1      1      2   bbb   yyy     11
```

**Option 1:**

```
In [29]: df.filter(regex='^aaa')
Out[29]:
   aaa_1  aaa_2  aaa_3
0      1      2     10
1      1      2     11
```

**Option 2:**

```
In [30]: df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('^aaa')]
Out[30]:
   aaa_1  aaa_2  aaa_3
0      1      2     10
1      1      2     11
```

Answer (score 1):

A less "pandaic" way is just using list comprehension:

```
df
   people_emotions_anger  people_emotions_joy  people_emotions_surprise  foo  \
0                      1                    2                         3    4   

   bar  
0    5  

df[[x for x in df.columns if x.startswith('people_emotions')]]
   people_emotions_anger  people_emotions_joy  people_emotions_surprise
0                      1                    2                         3
```